# Laravel Keep caching though cleared

Tags: php, linux, laravel, caching

I have an annoying problem on Laravel, Though I clear all cached it's still caching. I've try to rename routes as like :

```
Route::get('/damn', function () {
    dd(1);
});
```

it's should show me *1* but I when I try to check on browser the web still show me the normal view.

I was try with

```
php artisan config:cache  

php artisan route:cache  

php artisan cache:clear
```

and It's keep caching till I run

```
php artisan optimize
```

when I edited the route again , It's caching again and again and always must to run `artisan optimize`

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: php artisan route:clear

Comment: Is this on your local environment?

Comment: still not working ...

Comment: no, it's on development server

Answer (score 2):

You can simply place the below code in your routes/web.php file of Laravel application. Then access this URL in the browser to clear the cache of Laravel application.

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return "Cache is cleared";
});
```

Comment: How could this answer be correct if @Aaron just said *cache:clear* is not working for him?
In my experience, cache:clear keep not working... even programatically called.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have another route with the same `uri` and it returns a view.